# CPU bound Java process stalls Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, gwt, operating-system, kernel

When I run GWT compiler, it causes other programs intermittently stall till the compilation ends.

A preemptive OS like Windows is not expected to starve other processes when one CPU intensive process starts running. And that's how it works for most other processes other than the GWT build.

This was not the case with Java 7. So I suspect it's got something to do with the Java 8 JVM.

In task manager, the CPU intensive Java process has normal priority. So I am wondering what's causing this.